# Hardwood Deck Board Acclimation

Tags: hardwood, decking

So, I'm installing a deck.  Just bought the decking, which should be here in 2-3 weeks.  (A mix of Ipe and Cimaru)

I've seen mixed answers on the "right way" to acclimate it.

Is "in the garage" acceptable?   It would be on the floor, separated with shims, etc - but just not outside.  Two reasons...

1. Theft
2. Covering it.  Most places say "Cover with plywood".  They obviously wrote those instructions more than a year ago.  Even "Covering with OSB" would mean at least 3 sheets, at $50ish each.

Is tarping an option if I have to keep it outside?  Not wrapped with a tarp - more like a sunshade lean-to (so, the tarp isn't actually touching anything, and is open on all 4 sides)

Comment: https://www.hardwoodtogo.net/before-you-build-a-deck-wait/ seems to indicate that a garage is fine as long as your garage is unconditioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outdoor would be preferable as that'll match the conditions of where you'll be using the wood. As mentioned, an unconditioned garage is ok so as long as it gets roughly similar temperatures and humidity. Technically you're not suppose to let it sit directly on concrete (or ground) during acclimation. So if you put it in the garage, shim under the bottom board if you can.

I just finished laying the boards on my deck the other day (roughly 600 sqft) and wish I could use Ipe but it's way too expensive for me.

Comment: That was my thought... and, I did know about the "not putting it on the ground" rule - precisely why I saved my extra post tops.  5.5" of shim!  Now, to find a cheap source of stringers to separate the individual boards...